# Как превести дату «10» августа 2018г. в метку времени Unix

Tags: php

Вопрос полностью описан в заголовке.

Comment: А какой часовой пояс?

Comment: в данном случаи это важно? Тут он не имеет значения, мне главное что бы эта дата бала преобразована в число.

Comment: В один и тот же UTC в Москве может быть 10-е августа, а в Мексике 9-е.

Comment: ну пусть это будет московский пояс, мне это не так важно, мне нужно перевести эту дату в число для дальнейшего сравнения с другой датой.

Comment: Как то так наверное: `strtotime("10 August 2018")`

Comment: проблема в том что скрипту передаётся дата написанная русскими буквами а не английскими

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смею предположить, что можно реализовать так:

```
function getUnix($str) {
$keywords = [
    "/понедельник/" => "monday", // здесь могут быть дни недели. не стал вставлять.
    "/воскресенье/" => "sunday", 
    "/послезавтра/" => "+2 days",
    "/месяцев/" => "months",
    "/вторник/" => "tuesday",
    "/январ(ь|я)/" => "january", 
    "/феврал(ь|я)/" => "february", 
    "/апрел(ь|я)/" => "april", 
    "/ма(й|я)/" => "may", 
    "/июн(ь|я)/" => "june", 
    "/июл(ь|я)/" => "july", 
    "/август(а)/" => "august", 
    "/сентябр(ь|я)/" => "september", 
    "/октябр(ь|я)/" => "october", 
    "/ноябр(ь|я)/" => "november", 
    "/декабр(ь|я)/" => "december"
];

return strtotime(
           preg_replace(
               array_keys($keywords), 
               array_values($keywords), 
               strtolower($str))
    );

}

echo getUnix("10 августа 2018 10:22:23"); // output: 1533889343
```